# Deploy docker image (not Dockerfile) to Heroku?

Tags: docker, heroku

I want to deploy an existing Docker image to Heroku, where there is no Dockerfile in the local directory. (I created the Docker `foo:bar` image using datasette, and I don't know where it puts the Docker image).

These are the Docker images I have available:

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY                                     TAG        IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
foo                                            bar        d41xxxc69862        About an hour ago   1.08GB
<none>                                         <none>     af079eb9ceda        About an hour ago   980MB
```

I want to deploy the first docker image (`foo:bar`) to Heroku.

I have tried doing `heroku create my-app-12355`, then:

```
heroku container:push web -a my-app-12355
```

But this gives me:

```
  ▸    No images to push
```

How do I specify the name of the image? I think [the section on "Building and pushing images" in the documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime) is what I need, but I don't understand what "app" and "process-type" should be.

UPDATE: I tried:

```
docker tag d41xxxc69862 registry.heroku.com/my-app-12355/web
docker push registry.heroku.com/my-app-12355/web
```

But when I do `heroku container:push web -a my-app-12355` I still get `No images to push`. How do I tell it where the image is?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Heroku: How to release an existing image in gitlab CI/CD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50909812/heroku-how-to-release-an-existing-image-in-gitlab-ci-cd)

Answer (score 23):

Useful Link: https://toedter.com/2016/11/05/deploying-spring-boot-apps-to-heroku-using-docker/

I think you need to first tag your image and then push it to heroku registry:

```
docker tag d41xxxc69862 registry.heroku.com/my-app-12355/web
docker push registry.heroku.com/my-app-12355/web
```

d41xx is image id. Or you can try {image name}/{tag} e.g. foo/bar

Possible process-types are web, worker and image.

After docker push you need to run docker release command as per this [link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1426)

```
heroku container:release web --app=my-app-12355 -- you don't require the '/' before the app name. That worked for me.
```

Comment: Thanks! I did `docker tag d41xxxc69862 registry.heroku.com/my-app-12355/web` followed by `docker push registry.heroku.com/my-app-12355/web` and both ran OK. But when I do `heroku container:push web -a my-app-12355` I still see `No images to push`.

Comment: Also, not sure if you would expect anything to be at `https://registry.heroku.com/my-app-12355/web` or `https://registry.heroku.com/my-app-12355` (sorry, I'm very new to both Heroku and Docker and don't understand how they fit together...). But I see 404s at both addresses.

Comment: After `docker tag d41xxxc69862 registry.heroku.com/my-app-12355/web` and `docker push registry.heroku.com/my-app-12355/web` there is no need for container:push command. As per the article above the application should be accessible at `https://my-app-12355.herokuapp.com`

Comment: The above commands was working last week. Seems that is no longer working. Someone can help us here?

Comment: Just to clarify i was using this guide as a ref https://blog.devcenter.co/deploy-asp-net-core-2-0-apps-on-heroku-eea8efd918b6

Comment: [The Docker docs for push](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/push/#concurrent-uploads) suggest that I might need to do a `docker commit` before tag and push?

Comment: Hello @Richard, you have any news regarding this?

Comment: Hey, are you deploying a .net app?

Comment: @Richard I believe you need to run `heroku container:release web --app={app name} command`

Comment: @Richard this answer worked for me, I believe it should be marked as the correct answer

Comment: I followed the steps. But I'm getting the error as `No command specified for process type web` when I tried `heroku container:release web --app={app name}`

Answer (score 14):

When pushing docker images to heroku, make sure your **Dockerfile** is named with an Uppercase "D". Heroku CLI does not seem to recognize **dockerfile** (with lowercase "D") as a viable name for searching the image file, although docker itself does. I fixed this issue with this solution. hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

You have to rename your file: from `dockerfile` to `Dockerfile`.

Answer (score 3):

```sh
heroku container:push image_name -a=app_name
```

Answer (score -1):

The important part is to add the app name to the Dockerfile, so rename Dockerfile to be Dockerfile.web and respectively for any docker-compose services. Then you can simply push all at once with

```
heroku container:push --recursive --context-path .
```

Comment: please delete your answer, the question is about pushing an existing image where the Dockerfile does not exist.