# How do I deploy a Dockerized multi-image JS app to Heroku?

Tags: docker, heroku

I want to deploy a simple web app to Heroku.

The front-end, back-end, and database of my web app are bundled together with `docker-compose`.

The [Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/local-development-with-docker-compose#pushing-your-containers-to-heroku) says that typing `heroku container:push web` should be sufficient to push my app to Heroku, once I have created the appropriate images with `docker-compose`. This doesn't work for me: the Keroku CLI tells me `No images to push`.

Adding a `-a myAppName` tag doesn't help either, nor do [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50788844/3272066) on Stack Overflow.

I would prefer not to try [this solution](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1191), as it would pollute my source control with Heroku-specific configuration.

What can I do to understand what is not working and why?

Answer (score 0):

Docker compose on Heroku is just for local development. You should look at heroku.yml for deployment. Reference. [Heoku.yml](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml)