# Customize run command for heroku container:release

Tags: javascript, docker, heroku

On Heroku I'm trying to release a pushed image as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50788844/2771889

```sh
docker build --file Dockerfile.prod --tag registry.heroku.com/my-app/web .
heroku container:login
docker push registry.heroku.com/my-app/web
heroku container:release web
```

My `heroku.yml` looks like this (used when I deploy from GitHub, and works fine):

```yaml
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile.prod
release:
  image: web
  command:
    - yarn typeorm migration:run && yarn console seed
run:
  web: yarn start:prod
```

It seems that the `run` command is not taken into account. When running `container:release` the logs show:

> Starting process with command `node`

Whereas during a release from GitHub I'd see the correct command:

> Starting process with command `/bin/sh -c yarn start:prod`

The `release` command however is recognized and executed correctly.

How can I make sure `container:release` runs the container with the correct command?

Comment: random thought.. did you try adding "image: web" to the run command?

Comment: Where? I'm running `heroku container:release web`, which recognizes the correct image (and also runs the release command).

Comment: Try adding it to your run section. In the `release` section you have a line `image: web`. Try to copy that line into the `run` section as well.. it doesn't know where to run the command at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add a `CMD` to my Dockerfile:

```
# ...

CMD yarn start:prod
```

This doesn't break GitHub deployments with `heroku.yml`.